# OpenAI API: New version (v1) of the OpenAI Python package appears to contain breaking changes

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have been playing with openai==0.28.1 and created a few projects by following examples from *deeplearning.ai* short courses that use ChatGPT and other OpenAI models (courses for ChatGPT, [LangChain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LangChain), and more). Until today, everything worked without any problems.

Today I created another project with corresponding a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and installed the OpenAI library. This time it was openai==1.1.0 (PyPI already has it [updated to 1.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/openai/#history) since then).

As a result, all OpenAI API code stopped working as API objects appear to be renamed and functions/parameters changed between versions 0.28.1 and 1.1.0.

I tried to google any breaking changes and any release notes to no avail. I did find indirect confirmation that APIs changed while browsing [version history for README.md](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/commit/08b8179a6b3e46ca8eb117f819cc6563ae74e27d) that changed its examples between two versions as part of the [massive V1 PR](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/pull/677).

Are there any documented breaking changes or documentation on how to maintain code for previous versions besides the obvious option of installing older package version *openai=0.28.1*?

Comment: Does this changelog help? https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/631

Comment: this explains a lot , thank you @STerliakov

Answer (score 2):

OpenAI Python SDK `v1.1.0` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/releases/tag/v1.1.0) on November 6, 2023. It features the latest releases from OpenAI's first-ever DevDay (assistants, multimodality, tools, dall-e-3, tts, etc.).

See the official [OpenAI Python SDK markdown file](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/baa9f07f5b503017ea6dae8f047d3cfc1ee22c37/api.md).