OpenAI API upgrade from 0.28 to 1.x
I am trying to upgrade the OpenAI 0.28 version to 1.2.2. For doing that I defined the client and replaced the openai chatcompletion with client.
Below is the constant file which will be used in the main file to get the keys from environment.
OPENAI_API_BASE = 'api_base'
OPENAI_API_ENGINE = 'gpt-35-turbo-0613'
OPENAI_API_KEY = 'api_key'
OPENAI_API_TYPE = 'api_type'
OPENAI_API_VERSION = 'api_version'
OPENAI_API_TEMPERATURE = 0

This is the main file which I am using for completing the text. In this file I wanted to make upgrade the OpenAI version. I don't want to change the structure of the below code
ROLE_KEY = 'role'
ROLE_VALUE = 'user'
CONTENT_KEY = 'content'

@backoff.on_exception(
    backoff.expo,
    (openai.APIError, openai.Timeout, openai.RateLimitError, KeyError),
    max_tries=1
)
def _get_completion(it_app: str):
    """
    Function to make an API call to OpenAI Chat Completion endpoint and receive a response.
    """
    prompt = it_app
    messages = [{ROLE_KEY: ROLE_VALUE, CONTENT_KEY: prompt}]

    try:
        client = AzureOpenAI(
                    azure_endpoint=const.OPENAI_API_BASE, 
                    api_key=const.OPENAI_API_KEY,
                    api_version=const.OPENAI_API_VERSION
                    )
        
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=const.OPENAI_API_ENGINE,
            messages=messages,
            temperature=const.OPENAI_API_TEMPERATURE,
        )
        
        return response.choices[0].message.content
    except openai.BadRequestError as e:
        print(str(e))


class TextCompletion():

    def __init__(self, config: dict[str, str, str, str]):
        """
        :param config: dictionary containing the following keys: 'api_type', 'api_key', 'api_base', 'api_version'
        """
        super().__init__()
        openai.api_type = config[const.OPENAI_API_TYPE]
        openai.api_key = config[const.OPENAI_API_KEY]
        openai.api_base = config[const.OPENAI_API_BASE]
        openai.api_version = config[const.OPENAI_API_VERSION]

    def predict(self, model_input: str):

        openai_results = _get_completion(model_input)
        return openai_results

This is the code I am using to test
config = {
    const.OPENAI_API_BASE : 'api_base',
    const.OPENAI_API_ENGINE : 'api_engine',
    const.OPENAI_API_KEY : 'api_key',
    const.OPENAI_API_TYPE : 'api_type',
    const.OPENAI_API_VERSION : 'api_version',
}

text_completion = TextCompletion(config)
print(text_completion.predict(model_input='which game is famound in India?'))

Its throwing APIConnection error, while this works for OpenAI 0.28 version.

Could you put up a minimal, reproducible example.

Could you check on this first - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77435356/openai-api-new-version-v1-of-the-openai-python-package-appears-to-contain-bre
Here is the migration guide for 1.x - https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

If you are not using any proxy or any kind of firewall etc. You can raise this issue in Community Forum, treat it as "Persistent Error" - https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/python-library-error-types

@PriyanshuJha somehow API keys are properly not fetched from config file, or maybe client need to be defined in class. I tried by I am not getting

You can define client in init that would define it in class, just add this -
self.client = AzureOpenAI(
azure_endpoint=const.OPENAI_API_BASE,
api_key=const.OPENAI_API_KEY,
api_version=const.OPENAI_API_VERSION
)
And then _get_completion() would only have completion.create function in it.

Also you would have to check for the credentials yourself, like add some print statements also check with this const variable.

Also for the sake of testing just increase max_tries like 5 or something in the decorator function backoff.on_exception. I think this decorator might be causing some issue.
